Preview is returning the published post. I want the modified post
I'm working in a Next.js 13 app, using Contentful CMS. I have the rights ENV vars and i want to have the preview of each post before to publish it.
I wrapped my _app.js with
import { ContentfulLivePreviewProvider } from "@contentful/live-preview/react";
   <ContentfulLivePreviewProvider
      enableInspectorMode
      enableLiveUpdates
      locale="en-US"
    >
     ...

I have the api/preview route
import contentfulService from "@/src/services/contentfulService";
import { COOKIE_NAME_PRERENDER_BYPASS } from "next/dist/server/api-utils";

export default async function preview(req, res) {
  const { secret, slug } = req.query;

  if (secret !== process.env.NEXT_CW_CONTENTFUL_PREVIEW_SECRET || !slug) {
    return res.status(401).json({ message: "Invalid token" });
  }

  
  const content = await contentfulService.getPreviewResortDetailsBySlug(slug);

  // If the slug doesn't exist prevent preview mode from being enabled
  if (!content) {
    return res.status(401).json({ message: "Invalid slug" });
  }

  // Enable Preview Mode by setting the cookies
  res.setDraftMode({ enable: true });

  const headers = res.getHeader("Set-Cookie");

  if (Array.isArray(headers)) {
    res.setHeader(
      "Set-Cookie",
      headers.map((cookie) => {
        if (cookie.includes(COOKIE_NAME_PRERENDER_BYPASS)) {
          return cookie.replace("SameSite=Lax", "SameSite=None; Secure");
        }
        return cookie;
      })
    );
  }

  res.setHeader("Location", slug);
  return res.status(307).end();
}

I'm replacing all the content with updated content in my component
import { useContentfulLiveUpdates } from "@contentful/live-preview/react";
const updatedResortDetails = useContentfulLiveUpdates(resortDetails);

And finally, where i have my contentful services, i had this client for normal content:
const client = contentful.createClient({
  accessToken: process.env.NEXT_CW_CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN,
  environment: process.env.NEXT_CW_CONTENTFUL_ENVIRONMENT,
  space: process.env.NEXT_CW_CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID,
});

So i created a new one (i don't know if this is ok) with preview token and host
const previewClient = contentful.createClient({
  accessToken: process.env.NEXT_CW_CONTENTFUL_PREVIEW_TOKEN,
  space: process.env.NEXT_CW_CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID,
  environment: process.env.NEXT_CW_CONTENTFUL_ENVIRONMENT,
  host: "preview.contentful.com",
});

And finally i'm using this previewClient in this function
/**
 * get resort-specific details
 * @param slug
 */
const getPreviewResortDetailsBySlug = async (resortSlug) => {
  const content = await previewClient.getEntries({
    content_type: pageContentTypes.resort,
    "fields.resortSlug": resortSlug,
    "metadata.tags.sys.id[nin]": "mbGolf",
    include: 10,
  });

  if (content && content.items && content.items.length) {
    return {
      id: content.items[0].sys.id,
      ...content.items[0].fields,
    };
  } else {
    return null;
  }
};

which is a copy of getResortDetailsBySlug, the same function but uses client instead previewClient.
After to do all this things, and setup the preview in Contentful, i can see the live preview in contentful APP, but data never changes. I'm adding a console.log in  the api/preview file to see if content changes, but no. I got the same content that is published, i want to see the live changes that i'm doing.
Someone knows what i'm missing? Thanks in advance
